# protractor problem: not working consistently

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I work with `protractor v5.4.2`, then i have a issue regarding the consistency of my scripts, the problem the same script sometimes it works the next run it doesn't.

I tried changing jasmine and protractor versions but no luck.

Generaly the errors are :

> -Element not interectable.
>   -No element found using locator. Despite the elements are present and displayed so logicly they are selectabale correctly

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you have flaky tests. Basically this means you try to interact with the DOM while it has not yet been fully updated. Not a true answer but maybe [this](https://christianlydemann.com/life-saving-protractor-utilities-to-fix-flaky-end-to-end-tests/) will help you?

Comment: Hello @Mathyn im very thankfull for you reply, i've already tried the sleep and wait methods for charging elements but i had always the same error, the problem that it works sometimes and other times it doesn't